# How to fix the problem 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'db_mysql:3306' (111)?

Tags: python, mysql, docker, microservices, fastapi

I've recently tried to dockerize my FastAPI Python server (also to replicate / double it). Before I had only MySQL server in a docker container and had everything fine, but when I also made a service out of my web server, it couldn't ever connect to MySQL server, so the app doesn't work now.

Here is the snippet of server DB init connector in app

```py
from fastapi import FastAPI
import mysql.connector


app = FastAPI()

dbconfig = {
  "host": "localhost",
  "database": "server_db",
  "user": "db_user",
  "password": "user-password"
}

# Checking DB connection
try:
    init_cnx = mysql.connector.connect(
        host='localhost',
        user='db_user',
        password='user-password'
    )
    cursor = init_cnx.cursor()
    cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES LIKE 'server_db'")
    if cursor.fetchone() == None:
        # Create DB in case one doesn't exist
        cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE server_db")
        cursor.execute("USE server_db")
        cursor.execute("CREATE TABLE Messages ("
                        "message_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,"
                        "sender_name VARCHAR(32),"
                        "message_text VARCHAR(64),"
                        "created_at DATE,"
                        "user_messages_count INT,"
                        "PRIMARY KEY (message_id));")
        print('DB Created!')
    cursor.close()
    init_cnx.close()
except mysql.connector.Error as err:
    print("On init_cnx:", err)


# DB I/O function
async def execute_db_query(query, cursor_buffered=False):
    cnx = mysql.connector.connect(**dbconfig)
    try:
        cursor = cnx.cursor(buffered=cursor_buffered)
        cursor.execute("USE server_db")
        cursor.execute(query)
        result = cursor.fetchall()
        cnx.commit()
        print("Query executed successfully!")
        return result
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error executing query:", e)
    finally:
        if cnx:
            cnx.close()


# Get root function, just to check if app is connected to DB
@app.get("/")
async def get_root():
    try:
        entries_count = await execute_db_query("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Messages", cursor_buffered=True)
        return {"Messages entries": entries_count[0][0]}
    except Exception as e:
        return {"Error": e}
```

Dockerfile for server

```
FROM python:3.11.4-slim-bookworm

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

COPY server.py .
EXPOSE 8000
CMD ["uvicorn", "server:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000"]
```

init.sql script

```sql
CREATE USER 'db_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user-password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  db_mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
    volumes:
      - "./mysql/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql"
      - "./mysql/db_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./mysql/mysql_logs:/var/log/mysql"
    networks:
      - dummy_network

  server_1:
    image: dummy_msg_server
    ports:
      - "8081:8000"
    networks:
      - dummy_network
    #command: sh -c "sleep 60s"
    depends_on:
      - db_mysql

  server_2:
    image: dummy_msg_server
    ports:
      - "8082:8000"
    networks:
      - dummy_network
    #command: sh -c "sleep 60s"
    depends_on:
      - db_mysql

volumes:
  db_mysql_data: #external: true

networks:
  dummy_network:
    driver: bridge
```

Though, trying to use API before MySQL container fully initialized may cause errors, it's not the case, because I'm waiting till MySQL server says it's ready to handle requests. Unless that, I don't try to connect to MySQL server.

I tried connecting with hostname/ip-address.
Tried to change python:3.11.4 image in dockerfile to earlier debian release and to not slim image.
Tried to excplicitly use one common network for containers. Docker keeps showing, containers are in one network, and curl request from server container returns something.
Also, docker-compose.yml used to have ports for db_mysql service 3306:3306. Guess, it's not the case as well.

**UPD 1.** While investigating, found out that if the DB is already created, then the app has no problems with sending requests to it and getting proper responses. Its only problem is that it can't create a DB, using creating script in the code.
(Guess, I should update code blocks, since the project is quite on another stage right now.)

Comment: Why does your error message say port 33060? MySQL uses port 3306.

Comment: As far as I see, MySQL Server exposes both 3306 and 33060 ports. The last one, I tried, was 33060. Both options lead to the error.

Comment: Are you still able to connect to your mysql server that is in the docker container from your host system (without changing anything in your `docker-compose` file)? I would assume that you ran your mysql docker container in host network mode before.

Comment: Yeah, it works. I just had to change connector host from "db_mysql" to "localhost" in python file, since first works only in docker network environment.
Also had to write ports: - 3306:3306 in docker-compose file.

Comment: `Also had to write ports: - 3306:3306 in docker-compose file.` so you changed something in you `docker-compose` setup.

Comment: Yes, I automatically mapped ports, and told so. What's the matter?

You see, I tried to dockerize server.py and had to change config. Now that you asked to check if undockerized server connects to DB server, I had to return port mapping (obviously I wouldn't be able to connect without that action). The result is server.py on host machine can connect to DB Server in container, and the same server.py file in container still can't with the same error.

Comment: That can change how MySQL perceives where the connection (from which IP) the connection is coming from. I assume that the setup for the `root` user is restricted, because you shouldn’t use the `root` user for other purposes than configuring the database. Create a new user for which you grant access to the database from all host (`%`) and use that user.

Comment: `obviously I wouldn't be able to connect without that action` it depends  on Linux  (and I think it works with wsl2 on windows as well) you can connect to a docker container from the host without port mapping by using the containers IP.

Comment: I created user with `CREATE USER 'db_user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'user-password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'db_user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` in *init.sql* file. I mapped this file with the volume `- "./mysql/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql"`. I successfully connected to mysql container in an interactive mode, using new user login/pass. Sure I also changed connector user & password parameters. Still I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encountered a problem where both the servers and database containers were starting simultaneously, causing issues. The first (and last) attempt to connect to the database server happened before it was ready to accept any connections.

To solve this, I decided to add a health check to the *docker-compose.yml* file:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  db_mysql:
    image: mysql:8
    restart: always
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "root"
    volumes:
      - "./mysql/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql"
      - "./mysql/db_mysql_data:/var/lib/mysql"
      - "./mysql/mysql_logs:/var/log/mysql"
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "mysqladmin", "ping", "-h", "localhost", "-uroot", "-proot"]
      timeout: 1s
      interval: 40s
      retries: 5

  server_1:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8081:8000"
    depends_on:
      db_mysql:
        condition: service_healthy

  server_2:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "8082:8000"
    depends_on:
      db_mysql:
        condition: service_healthy

volumes:
  db_mysql_data: #external: true
```

With this configuration, the containers for the servers won't start until the health check confirms that the database server is ready.

However, there's a possibly better approach to handle this situation, which involves using the [wait-for-it.sh](https://github.com/vishnubob/wait-for-it) script. I personally know some experienced backend developers, who also use Docker containers to split their apps into microservices. They have spoken positively about using this script. Although I haven't personally tried it, I recommend considering it as an alternative solution.